# I am having trouble loading the google maps in chrome

Tags: javascript

I am trying to have google maps display the address when entering the postal code. It works fine in Firefox but for some reason the js libraries does not load in chrome and i am not able to display the ma in chrome. Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="form.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="form.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places&callback=initMap" async defer></script>
    <script language="javascript" src="https://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&key=AIzaSyAGF0XkTW0tAXZLMw-6AI9106H68N0aWio"></script>
    <script src="https://gitcdn.github.io/bootstrap-toggle/2.2.2/js/bootstrap-toggle.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row" style="background-color:#ffffff;">
        <div class="col-12 col-md-12" style="background-color:#ffffff;">
<nav class="navbar navbar-toggleable-md navbar-light bg-faded" style="background-color:#ffffff;">
  <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarText" aria-controls="navbarText" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar w/ text</a>

      <!-- Define your search form -->
      <form class="navbar-form navbar-left" role="search">
        <!-- Define a button to toggle the search area -->
        <button id='search-button' class='btn btn-default '><img src="magnifying-glass-search1.png"></button>
        <!-- Create your entire search form -->
        <div id='search-form' class="form-group">
          <div class="input-group">
            <span id='search-icon' class="input-group-addon"><img src="magnifying-glass-search1.png"></span>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>

        <script type='text/javascript'>
      // When your page loads
      $(function(){
         // When the toggle areas in your navbar are clicked, toggle them
         $("#search-button, #search-icon").click(function(e){
             e.preventDefault();
             $("#search-button, #search-form").toggle();
         });
      })  
      </script>

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarText">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto nav justify-content-end">
      <li class="nav-item active">
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
      </li>
    </ul>
    <span class="navbar-text">
      <a href="" style="color:#000000;">Post</a>
      <a href="" style="color:#000000;">Sign In</a>
    </span>
    </div>
    </nav>
    <hr>

    <h3 style="text-align:center;">Lorem Ipsum</h3>
    <h4 style="text-align:center;">"Neque porro quisquam est qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit..."</h4>
    <h5 style="text-align:center;">"There is no one who loves pain itself, who seeks after it and wants to have it, simply because it is pain..."</h5>
    <div>
        <form style="padding:10px 40px 10px 40px;border:1px solid #ababab;border-radius: 5px;">
        <span><strong>Account Sign Up</strong></span>
        <div class="form-group">
        <div class="form-group row">
            <label for="name" class="col-sm-12 col-form-label">Name</label>
            <div class="col-sm-6" id="fname">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="firstName" aria-describedby="fname" placeholder="First Name">
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6" id="lname">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="lastName" aria-describedby="lname" placeholder="Last Name">
            </div>
         </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Email address</label>
            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email1" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="name@example.com">
            <small id="emailHelp" class="form-text text-muted">We'll never share your email with anyone else.</small>
         </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Create Your Password</label>
            <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" placeholder="Password"><br />
            <input type="password" class="form-control" id="confirmPassword" placeholder="Confirm Password">
        </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Phone Number</label>
            <small id="textHelp" class="form-text text-muted">Other people will never see your phone number.</small>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="phone" placeholder="Phone Number"><br />
          </div>
        </form>
        </div><!--end of 1st form-->

        <div style="padding-top:15px;">
            <form style="padding:10px 40px 10px 40px;border:1px solid #ababab;border-radius: 5px;">
            <span><strong>Profile</strong></span>
            <div class="form-group">
            <div class="form-group row">
                <label for="name" class="col-sm-12 col-form-label">Profile Image</label>
                <div class="col-sm-2" id="profileImg">
                <img src="anonymous.jpg">
                <input type="file" class="form-control-file" id="InputFile" aria-describedby="fileHelp">
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-10" id="aboutMe">
                <textarea class="form-control" id="aboutMe" rows="3" placeholder="About me"></textarea>
                </div>
              </div>
             </div>


              <div class="form-group">
                <div class="form-group row">
                    <div class="col-sm-2" id="chooseGender">
                    <h5 style="padding-top:6px;">I am</h5>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-4" id="selectGender">
                        <select class="form-control" id="gender">
                        <option>Male</option>
                        <option>Female</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
              </div>

              <div class="form-group">
              <div class="form-group row">
                        <label for="exampleInputbirthday" class="col-sm-12">Birthday</label>
                        <small class="col-sm-12" id="textHelp" class="form-text text-muted">You must be 18 or older. Other people won't see your birthday.</small>
                        <div class="col-sm-4" id="month">
                        <select class="form-control" id="exampleMonth">
                                              <option selected>Month</option>
                                              <option>January</option>
                                              <option>February</option>
                                              <option>March</option>
                                              <option>April</option>
                                              <option>May</option>
                                              <option>June</option>
                                              <option>July</option>
                                              <option>August</option>
                                              <option>September</option>
                                              <option>October</option>
                                              <option>November</option>
                                              <option>December</option>
                        </select>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-4" id="day">
                        <select class="form-control" id="selectDay">
                        <option selected>Day</option>
                        <script>
                            var min = 1,
                            max = 31,
                            select = document.getElementById('selectDay');

                            for (var i = min; i<=max; i++){
                            var opt = document.createElement('option');
                            opt.value = i;
                            opt.innerHTML = i;
                            select.appendChild(opt);
                            }
                        </script>
                        </select>
                  </div>

                  <div class="col-sm-4" id="year">
                  <select class="form-control" id="selectYear">
                  <option selected>Year</option>
                  <script>
                  var min = 1936,
                      max = 2089,
                      select = document.getElementById('selectYear');

                      for (var i = min; i<=max; i++){
                      var opt = document.createElement('option');
                      opt.value = i;
                      opt.innerHTML = i;
                      select.appendChild(opt);
                      }

                select.value = new Date().getFullYear();
                  </script>
                  </select>
                  </div>
                </div>

              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="occupation">Occupation</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="occupation" placeholder="Title"><br />
              </div>
            </form>
    </div><!--end of 2nd form-->


            <div style="padding-top:15px;">
                <form style="padding:10px 40px 10px 40px;border:1px solid #ababab;border-radius: 5px;">
                <span><strong>Location</strong></span>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <div>
                            <label for="labelCountry">Country</label>
                            <select name="country" class="form-control" id="country" onchange="stateMenu(this.value);">
                                                  <option value="" selected>Select a Country</option>
                                                  <option value="US">United States</option>
                                                  <option value="CA">Canda</option>
                                                  <option value="In">India</option>
                                                  <option value="UK">United Kingdom</option>
                                                  <option value="FR">France</option>
                                                  <option value="CH">China</option>
                                                  <option value="JA">Japan</option>
                                                  <option value="GE">Germany</option>
                                                  <option value="AU">Australia</option>
                                                  <option value="RU">Russia</option>
                                                  <option value="CA">Canada</option>
                                                  <option value="PA">Pakistan</option>
                                                  <option value="IT">Italy</option>
                                                  <option value="SP">Spain</option>
                                                  <option value="SK">South Korea</option>
                                                  <option value="PH">Philippines</option>
                                                  <option value="EN">England</option>
                                                  <option value="EG">Egypt</option>
                                                  <option value="SI">Singapore</option>
                                                  <option value="GR">Greece</option>
                                                  <option value="BR">Brazil</option>
                            </select>
                            </div>
                            <div>
                            <label for="stateLabel">Province/State</label>
                            <select class="form-control" id="state" placeholder="Province/State">
                                <option selected value=''>Select a Province</option>
                            </select>
                      </div>

        <div class="form-group row">
            <div class="col-sm-6">
            <label for="name" class="col-form-label">City</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="city" aria-describedby="city" placeholder="Enter your City">
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
            <label for="name" class="col-form-label">Town</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="town" aria-describedby="town" placeholder="Enter your Town">
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="form-group row">
                    <div class="col-sm-6" id="targetZip">
                        <label for="name" class="col-form-label">Postal/Zip Code</label>
                        <div id="map"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-6">

                    <input class="form-control controls" type="text" id="searchInput" placeholder="Enter postal code">
                    </div>

          </div>
        </div>

        </div>
                <div class="form-group row">
                    <div class="col-lg-6" style="padding-top:10px;">
                    <label for="name" class="col-form-label">There is no one who loves pain itself, who seeks after it and wants to have it, simply because it is pain..."</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-6" style="padding-top:10px;float:right;">
                    <div class="col-lg-4">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-4">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
                    </div>
          </div>
        </form>
    </div><!--end of 3rd form-->
    </div><!end of 1st column--->
    </div><!end of 1st row--->
    </div><!end of 1st container--->


    <!-- jQuery first, then Tether, then Bootstrap JS. -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-A7FZj7v+d/sdmMqp/nOQwliLvUsJfDHW+k9Omg/a/EheAdgtzNs3hpfag6Ed950n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js" integrity="sha384-DztdAPBWPRXSA/3eYEEUWrWCy7G5KFbe8fFjk5JAIxUYHKkDx6Qin1DkWx51bBrb" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-vBWWzlZJ8ea9aCX4pEW3rVHjgjt7zpkNpZk+02D9phzyeVkE+jo0ieGizqPLForn" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>


<!---JS Code--->
function initMap() {
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      center: {lat: -33.8688, lng: 151.2195},
      zoom: 13
    });
    var input = document.getElementById('searchInput');
    map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(input);

    var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input);
    autocomplete.bindTo('bounds', map);

    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        anchorPoint: new google.maps.Point(0, -29)
    });

    autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', function() {
        infowindow.close();
        marker.setVisible(false);
        var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
        if (!place.geometry) {
            window.alert("Autocomplete's returned place contains no geometry");
            return;
        }

        // If the place has a geometry, then present it on a map.
        if (place.geometry.viewport) {
            map.fitBounds(place.geometry.viewport);
        } else {
            map.setCenter(place.geometry.location);
            map.setZoom(17);
        }
        marker.setIcon(({
            url: place.icon,
            size: new google.maps.Size(71, 71),
            origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
            anchor: new google.maps.Point(17, 34),
            scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(35, 35)
        }));
        marker.setPosition(place.geometry.location);
        marker.setVisible(true);

        var address = '';
        if (place.address_components) {
            address = [
              (place.address_components[0] && place.address_components[0].short_name || ''),
              (place.address_components[1] && place.address_components[1].short_name || ''),
              (place.address_components[2] && place.address_components[2].short_name || '')
            ].join(' ');
        }

        infowindow.setContent('<div><strong>' + place.name + '</strong><br>' + address);
        infowindow.open(map, marker);

        //Location details
        for (var i = 0; i < place.address_components.length; i++) {
            if(place.address_components[i].types[0] == 'postal_code'){
                document.getElementById('postal_code').innerHTML = place.address_components[i].long_name;
            }
            if(place.address_components[i].types[0] == 'country'){
                document.getElementById('country').innerHTML = place.address_components[i].long_name;
            }
        }
        document.getElementById('location').innerHTML = place.formatted_address;
        document.getElementById('lat').innerHTML = place.geometry.location.lat();
        document.getElementById('lon').innerHTML = place.geometry.location.lng();
    });
}
```

Comment: What errors do you get in the developer tools console?

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'firstChild' of null

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'firstChild' of null
at Object._.og (js?libraries=places&callback=initMap:88 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'firstChild' of null
    at Object._.og (js?libraries=places&callback=initMap:88)
    at new tg (js?libraries=places&callback=initMap:90)
    at initMap (form.js:48)
    at js?libraries=places&callback=initMap:98
    at js?libraries=places&callback=initMap:56
    at js?libraries=places&callback=initMap:53
    at Array.<anonymous> (js?libraries=places&callback=initMap:56)

Comment: Please edit the code in your question down to the minimum needed to demonstrate the problem.  This is way too much code.  See [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for more information.